# OSX Lion New bash session rvm default ruby not used

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, osx-lion, rvm

I use OSX Lion. I have installed RVM and have put this line in my .bash_profile file.

```
[[ -s "/Users/Anand/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/Anand/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

I installed ruby-1.9.2-p290 and set it as default rvm ruby with this command:

```
rvm use --default ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

And when I checked `ruby-v`

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

The problem is, every time I open a new terminal window or a tab, the default ruby is not getting set. The system ruby is instead getting used. `ruby -v` gives this:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.3.2]
```

This also happens with reading .rvmrc file in a ruby project. When I'm inside a project and when a new tab gets opened, it gets me into the project directory but is not setting ruby according to .rvmrc in that project. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Just a vaguely related sidenote: For managing multiple ruby versions on one machine, also consider [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Comment: posted my solution below. there was a problem with the $PATH

Answer (score 15):

I got the problem. It was with $PATH. I have to put rvm related line in the .bash_profile as the last line.

Old .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

source $HOME/Dropbox/dotfiles/bashrc
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin:$PATH
```

New .bash_profile

```
source $HOME/Dropbox/dotfiles/bashrc
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And it worked. New windows and new tabs open up correctly with the default ruby i.e, ruby 1.9.2

Comment: YES. Finally this (insanely non-obvious) answer solved it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

I just fixed this very same issue.  Turns out it was a path issue.

try this

```
➜  ~  which ruby
```

if you are getting `/usr/bin/ruby`, the path to your original ruby installation is overshadowing the default install in your RVM installation.

I added the path to RVM *before* the path (see below)  to /usr/bin/ruby and it works as expected.

I use zsh as my shell, so I had to add this manually to my .zshrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting<br />
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

if you use bash

Your .bashrc probably looks like this

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

change it to this:

```
PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

and make sure you .bash_profile has this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

and you should be good to go.

Of course this means that your shell is going to look in your RVM directory first when looking for any command, but thats never caused any issues for me.

Comment: I use zsh. When I follow your instructions the right ruby version is used when opening a new terminal. However several new problems occur: rails server cannot be started (error: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2"), bundle install is not working anymore "Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first." How can this be fixed?

Comment: murze - my guess is you need to reinstall your gems with your new version of ruby.  look in your ~/.rvm/gems dir and see whats in there...that's where your new version of ruby should be looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1:

The command as listed is, you had switched '--default' and 'use'.

```
 rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Check if default is actually set:

```
$ rvm list default

Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

Some other troubleshooting tips in case that doesn't work. Are you sure your bash profile file is being loaded? Try just having 'source "/Users/Anand/.rvm/scripts/rvm' instead of the check, maybe something is wrong with the path? Username does that begin with capital letter?

Question #2: You must cd into the directory with the .rvmrc file explicitly for the magic to happen. I suppose starting a console in a certain location doesn't trigger rvm. I run into this when using pushd and popd to switch between folders.

Comment: I tried sourcing - `source /Users/Anand/.rvm/scripts/rvm` .. still `ruby -v` gives ruby-1.8.7. Even tried running bash_profile again, `source .bash_profile` but again `ruby -v` gives ruby-1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this first if `rvm --default use` doesn't work:

```
sudo rvm alias create default 1.9.2
```